# Displaying the date

Tags: php, html, css, timestamp

I trying to only show the date so for example `2018-04-09` and not the time. After that I want it to make it like `9 april 2018` but I can't change the database because I need the hours/seconds/minutes for an other thing. I did not found on the internet what I need in my case and what works for  me. I hope someone has a tip how to make this with some kind of code.

I am new to asking questions so if I miss something to make this question work tell me.

[image: My database]

Comment: I would change it using JS, let the php send the info and mask your text via js. You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: RTM: [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) or in php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I was curious if there is already some code that does this for me?'

Comment: there isn't much we can do here; not without code and the schema for this.

Answer (score 0):

it could be your SQL query

```
select DATE_FORMAT(create_time,'%d %b %Y') from Table where 1 = 1;
```